# Blogger remove description in mobile view

Tags: blog, mobile, blogger, blogspot

What javascript  should I use so that when screen size is less than 699px than description header should get removed any only blog name should be show.

```
if (screen.width <= 699) {
                // set display none for description
            }
```

Comment: None........... Google mobile search does this for you and can even use keywords and sentences not in the title or meta description.

Comment: Why not just enable one of Blogger's own mobile templates?